# How do I create a reference in my DB to a user from the ASP.NET build in usersystem?

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, asp.net-mvc-3, oodb

I'm trying to save an object in my OODB, that is basically a news item (a title, some text, a poster and a postdate).

I have no trouble retrieving the user object from the ASP.NET MembershipUser class.

but when I try to save, it seems not all of the data is recorded in my database. Below is the create method code sample:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Newsitem newsitem)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        newsitem.postdate = DateTime.Now;
        newsitem.originalposter = Membership.GetUser(User.Identity.Name, true /* userIsOnline */);

        db.newsitems.Add(newsitem);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");  
    }

    return View(newsitem);
}
```

For example when I load the object from my DB it lacks the username. This is my load method:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var news = (from n in newsDB.newsitems orderby n.postdate descending select n).Take(10);
    return View(news);
}
```

Anybody know why some of the variables of the object is not saved?

Comment: small unrelated tip: use DateTime.UtcNow instead of DateTime.Now. Will make your life much easier down the road. It is good practice to store all dates/times in UTC. ;-)

Comment: How is Newsitem.originalposter defined?

Comment: it is defined like this:

    public MembershipUser originalposter { get; set; }

but the MembershipUser is a build in ASP.NET userclass which has some readonly attributes including username. perhaps this is why i cant save it. i dont know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is best that you have defined originalposter as an GUID. If I remember correctly the default asp.net membership provider defines UserId's as Guid's.
If you do that, it will work.

Then you can do as follows:

```
newsitem.originalposter = (Guid)Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey;
```